# Can Dynamodb save method return haskey?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Currently I have a dynamodb table with hash key marked as DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey. That means whenever I will save in dynamodb table hashkey will be generated automatically as UUID. I dont need to specify one by myself.

Now I would like to know if there is a way that I can have this hashkey once record is saved in the table. Is there a way that save method returns the record object from which I can get this hashkey?

Thank you,

Prasad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the auto generated id from the model object after the `save()` method is executed successfully. Please note that `DynamoDBMapper class save() method` is defined as void. However, it does populate the auto generated id in the model object.

**Order id is defined as auto generated key:-**

```
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "orderId")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
```

**Order id is available in the "order" object as soon as the save() method is executed successfully:-**

```
dynamoDBMapper.save(order);     
System.out.println("Order id : " + order.getOrderId());
```

**Output:-**

```
Order id : f8b63e5b-eeff-43aa-bcaf-fdc245f43a7c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful. It worked for me.